# How to use exported interface from TypeScript definition file?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to use the typed version of `jssha` and have run `npm install @types/jssha --save` and installed the definitions (as well as the library itself).

In my test file I now have `import { jsSHA } from 'jssha'` and in the @types/jssha index.d.ts I see `export interface jsSHA {...}`

I would expect to be able to now call`jsSHA` in my test file, but that value is `undefined`.

How do I actually use the exported interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`export interface jsSHA {...}` is not an indicator how you should import it, because it's declared inside `declare namespace jsSHA {`.

When you look at toplevel exports in that definition file (at the very end), you see

```
declare var jsSHA: jsSHA.jsSHA;
export = jsSHA;
export as namespace jsSHA;
```

Whenever you see `export =`, the best way to import is via `import require`:

```
import jsSHA = require('jssha');

var shaObj = new jsSHA("SHA-512", "TEXT");
shaObj.update("This is a test");
var hash = shaObj.getHash("HEX");
```

If you are compiling with `module=commonjs`, this import will work too:

```
import * as jsSHA from 'jssha';
```

Comment: I was able to get the `import jsSHA from "jssha"` working with `module=commonjs` when also adding `"esModuleInterop": true`, before that, I was getting no error in vscode, but when compiling `TypeError: jssha_1.default is not a constructor`

Answer (score -1):

If it is actually an interface it is only used for building the js, ins't it? Then you need something like `/// <reference path="path to .d.ts" />` at the top of the file